# Angular 2: ngSwitch or ViewContainerRef.createComponent

Tags: angular

I have a case where I am dynamically creating components in a list (which refreshes a lot) and using `ngSwitch` like this:

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items'>
   <div [ngSwitch]="item.view">
        <view-one *ngSwitchCase="'one'"></view-one>
        <view-two *ngSwitchCase="'two'"></view-two>
        <view-three *ngSwitchCase="'three'"></view-three>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to know if there is a better more efficient way of doing this, or is this the proper way?

I've seen people dynamically creating components, but the api has changed so many times it is hard to know what is right. It appears that `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` might be an alternative?

Answer (score 7):

I prefer `createComponent()` instead of `ngSwitch` because I think its easier to test and extend. I have not seen any lack of performance yet.

This is a simplified form of my current approach:

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-item",
    template: `
        <div #placeholder></div>
    `
})
export class MyItemComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input() item: any;
    @ViewChild("placeholder", {read: ViewContainerRef}) placeholderRef: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        switch(this.item.view) {
            case "one":
                this.loadItem(OneItemComponent);
            case "two":
                this.loadItem(TwoItemComponent);
            default:
                throw new Error("Unknown item!");
        }
    }

    private loadItem(component: Type<any>) {
        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        const componentRef = this.placeholderRef.createComponent(factory);
        componentRef.instance.item = this.item;
        componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

Now you can use this the following way:

```
<my-item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></my-item>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! saved the day. componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); fixed the flickering issue that was caused by vcr.clear()

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I implemented dynamic components in my app:

```
export class DynamicComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    @Input() model: any;
    @Input() factory: ComponentFactory<any>;
    @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target: any;

    private initialized: boolean = false;
    private componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

    private updateComponent() {
        if (!this.initialized || !this.factory) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.componentRef) {
            this.componentRef.destroy();
        }

        this.componentRef = this.target.createComponent(this.factory);
        this.componentRef.instance.model = this.model;
        this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.updateComponent();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.initialized = true;
        this.updateComponent();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.componentRef) {
            this.componentRef.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

To make this work, you need a template containing

```
<div #target><div>
```

for this class, it's where the dynamically created component will appear.

And here's how it's used:

```
<dynamic [factory]="myFactory" [model]="myModel"></dynamic>
```

`myFactory` is a `ComponentFactory`, e.g.

```
let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
```

where `resolver` is a `ComponentFactoryResolver` (from `@angular/core`).

`myModel` is data that you can pass to the newly created component, and will be available as an `@Input()` parameter.